# Altium Designer: Getting a Parent Diagram for a Flat Hierarchy

Tags: circuit-design, schematics, altium

I paid someone to do a Pspice design for me in Altium Designer.  He created multiple subsheets but no parent sheet.  From my searching, I see that there are hierarchical designs and flat designs.  I think this design is flat.

What I need to do is create a parent sheet (either by conversion or some other method).  By parent sheet, I mean a sheet with all subsheets combined and wired together.  The diagram doesn't have to be pretty to start.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know about Altium in particular, but in general, a "flat" design does not have a "parent sheet". All connections between sheets are made by naming the nets.

Comment: If you want to turn it into a hierarchical design, you'd have to start by adding ports to each of the sub-sheets, and then create a top-level (parent) sheet that connects those ports together.

Comment: No way to automate it I guess? the subsheets already have ports.